# Jquery StopPropagation not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, dom, twitter-bootstrap, stoppropagation

I have this code working on Safari and Chrome , but not in Firefox . Is firefox having a problem with StopPropagation() ?

```
$(function() {
    // Setup drop down menu
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

    // Fix input element click problem
    $('.login-menu form').click(function(e) {
        alert(e.isPropagationStopped());
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert(e.isPropagationStopped());
    });
});​
```

Comment: Ps : Even e.StopImmediatePropagation is not working !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how your HTML looks but `stopPropagation` works fine in FireFox.

I think your expectations might be incorrect in what it does.

According to the documentation of [**stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

> **event.stopPropagation()**
>   Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
>   tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Assuming HTML like this for example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="login-menu">click anywhere</div>
</div>
```

This code works fine, the click event is not bubbling up:

```
$(function() {
    // Fix input element click problem
    $('.login-menu').click(function(e) {
        alert(e.isPropagationStopped());
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert(e.isPropagationStopped());
    });

    $("#parent").click(function(e){
        alert("parent received click");
    });
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/KUTxS/) - Works in FF - Does not bubble up event

Comment out the line `e.stopPropagation();` in the DEMO and as expected the event is bubbled up, showing the alert from the parent.

#### What is your expected behaviour?

You have not specified what it is you expect to happen.

If for example you expected the default action of the event no to be triggered you can use [**preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

> **event.preventDefault()**
>   If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

If you want to cover both, prevent the default action and prevent the event from bubbling up you either call both or simply use `return false` at the end of your method.

If you could elaborate what it is you are trying to achieve we can be more specific in suggestion a solution which works for you.

Comment: Thanks François. I'm trying to understand but it's not easy to me. What i'm trying to get working is the login button on this page : [link] (http://www.spotmaroc.com)

Comment: You have a few errors on your site, loading your site shows the following in the browser's debugger console: `GET http://www.spotmaroc.com/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css 404 (Not Found)` and `GET http://www.spotmaroc.com/boostrap.js 404 (Not Found)` and `GET https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/2.0-wip/js/bootstrap-modal.js 404 (Not Found)`. You might need to address those issues first, otherwise you would not know why your button is not working.

Comment: This worked great for me! Allowed me to prevent bubbling in Firefox (the problematic one), as well as Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

I run into the same problem, and fixed it as soon as I realized I made a couple of "distraction errors", might be helpful to some:

1) **Remember the "event" argument**:
The function which gets executed when the event is triggered (i.e. the function passed as argument to $('.login-menu form').click() ) should accept an argument which represents the event (by convention called 'event', or 'e' in most tutorials). Chrome allows you to forget about it, while Firefox requires it.

2) **Remember to clear Firefox's cache** (CTRL + F5):
If, like myself, you disable Chrome's cache for developing (tools -> Javascript Console -> options -> Disable cache (while DevTools is open) ), but don't do the same in Firefox (cause it's a little trickier to do, and I'm lazy), remember to reload your page using CTRL + F5

It now works like a charm, for me...

Comment: The "event" argument was the answer in my case. Thanks.

Comment: Nice one **"Chrome allows you to forget..."**. Worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (across all browsers, whether or not an event can be passed), I am using google map markers, and was not able to pass an event to the method:

```
var stopPropagation = function (event) {
    if (event && event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } 
    else if (window.event) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    else if (window.$.Event.prototype) {
        window.$.Event.prototype.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation` is used for stopping an event from triggering on parent elements.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Accus/2/ for an example on how it works.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Test</span>
    </div>​
<body>
```

JS:

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    console.log('span');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});

$('div').click(function(e) {
    console.log('div');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});

$('body').click(function(e) {
    console.log('body');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});

​
​
```

Comment: Seems like he may need to just return, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Petah , but that didn't work for me. Actually i only got a problem on Firefox .. and i'm really new to the DOM architecture so it can really help me. Thanks Anyway. You can check out the website if it can help you helping me :) [link](http://www.spotmaroc.com)

Comment: @KarimMortabit what version of Firefox?

Comment: @KarimMortabit well its working fine for me. So you either not telling us the full story, or you have some weird bug in your browser only.

Comment: @Petah Can you enter an e-mail or password in the login form ? I can't , the login form window shuts down when i click it. (Still only in Firefox..). Thanks for the help.