# Link tag 'a' stopPropagation() doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Using this:

```
function showFoo(e) {
    $(e.path[0].hash.replace('#', '.'))[0].scrollIntoView()
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancel = true;
    return false;
  }
  var links = this.getElementsByTagName('a')
  console.log(links)
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = showFoo
  }
```

Doesn't work on Firefox, but works on Chrome fine.

Comment: Try looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556452/jquery-stoppropagation-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't locate `path` as a valid `MouseEvent` property in any specification so I'm not sure it's even a standard property, but in either case Firefox does not support it, and you are likely receiving an error in your console.

However, you can just replace `e.path[0]` with the standard `e.currentTarget`. Better still you can replace the nasty `.onclick` with an `addEventListener` call, and then you can just use `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`.

```
function showFoo(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget.hash.replace('#', '.'))[0].scrollIntoView()
    //e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.returnValue = false;
    //e.cancel = true;
    //return false;
}
var links = this.getElementsByTagName('a')
console.log(links)
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    //links[i].onclick = showFoo
    links[i].addEventListener('click', showFoo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function showFoo(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('event', e);
  //$(e.path[0].hash.replace('#', '.'))[0].scrollIntoView()
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
console.log(links)

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', showFoo )
}
```

```html
<a href="#test"> See console output </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any errors in your console? I suspect that you are getting an error on the following line, which breaks the JS execution, which is causes the `stopPropigation` to not be executed. The error might be on this line:

```
$(e.path[0].hash.replace('#', '.'))[0].scrollIntoView()
```

When you index the array with `[0]`, you get the native JS object - not a jQuery object. Therefore, when you try to call the jQuery function `.scrollIntoView()` you should be getting an error. You can either wrap that indexed expression in a jQuery object or else use the `.eq()` function, which indexes an array and returns the result as a jQuery object.

```
$($(e.path[0].hash.replace('#', '.'))[0]).scrollIntoView()
//or
$(e.path[0].hash.replace('#', '.')).eq(0).scrollIntoView()
```

Personally, I prefer the second method since it looks cleaner.